# SQL Server Count Specific Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
+-----------+--------+
| FILE CODE | STATES |
+-----------+--------+
| TEST 1    | CA     |
| TEST 2    | CA     |
| TEST 1    | CA     |
| TEST 2    | CA     |
| TEST 3    | CA     |
| TEST 4    | CA     |
| TEST 5    | CA     |
| TEST 1    | AZ     |
| TEST 1    | LI     |
| TEST 4    | CA     |
| TEST 4    | CA     |
+-----------+--------+
```

THIS SHOULD BE THE OUTPUT 
(Please see image below it's counting but have some trouble on the OUTPUT)

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| FILECODE | STATES | COUNTS  |
+----------+--------+---------+
| TEST 1   |   CA   |       2 |
| TEST 1   |   AZ   |       1 |
| TEST 1   |   LI   |       1 |
| TEST 2   |   CA   |       2 |
| TEST 3   |   CA   |       1 |
| TEST 4   |   CA   |       3 |
| TEST 5   |   CA   |       1 |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    S.States, S.FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE, C.COUNTS
FROM 
    Master_Files S 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         States, FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE, 
         COUNT(FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE) as COUNTS  
     FROM 
         Master_Files 
     GROUP BY 
         States, FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE) C ON S.FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE = C.FIRST_MORTGAGE_PRIMARY_LOAN_TYPE 
                                                     AND S.States = C.States
```

[image]

Comment: this is a basic `group by`. try it first and post a question if you get stuck.

Comment: hint: use count() and group by

Comment: I already use that please see image above, that is my problem, Its counting but have multiple TEST 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use a subquery here. This query should be enough:

```
SELECT states, 
       first_mortgage_primary_loan_type, 
       Count(first_mortgage_primary_loan_type) AS COUNTS 
FROM   master_files 
GROUP  BY states, first_mortgage_primary_loan_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a hint: :)

```
SELECT FILECODE, STATES, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY FILECODE, STATES
```

As the comment said, this is a basic GROUP BY problem.
I advise you to make some exercises regarding `AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS` (`AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `COUNT` etc...) and `GROUP BY` statements

Comment: Tried search for it but can't see anything that can make my output, Im using COUNT and GroupBy.